# Performance tuning Spark's Word2Vec

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, word2vec

I want to improve the performance of Spark's Word2Vec model on a EMR cluster. I have around 54 GB of cleaned patent text data, and I want to train a Spark's Word2Vec on it. It looks like it is running, but I think the performance can be improved. Can someone give me advice on how to do this?

**Preprocessing steps taken:**

- Stripping special characters from the texts, and reducing unnecessary whitespaces.
- Tokenize words
- Remove stopwords from tokens
- Lemmatize words
- Remove too frequently occuring words (words that occur in more than 30% of the documents)

**Sample of the cleaned data**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[water, cooling, cooled, type, pre, burning, present, invention, provides, kind, water, cooling, ...|
|[new, energetic, liquid, invention, discloses, kind, new, energetic, liquid, made, head, outlet, ...|
|[pre, assembly, pre, disclosed, pre, cylindrical, body, member, extending, axially, opposite, pre...|
|[part, feed, ozone, feed, form, difference, ozone, concentration, space, wise, time, wise, premix...|
|[homogeneous, charge, thereof, invention, discloses, homogeneous, type, thereof, cover, arranged,...|
|[gasoline, pre, plug, pre, communicating, plug, associated, pre, respectively, gasoline, injected...|
|[pre, pre, homogeneous, charge, hcci, mode, providing, pre, fluidly, creating, radical, pre, achi...|
|[pre, 105, 351, another, aspect, pre, equal, greater, main, 107, 355, ieast, prior, main, aspect,...|
|[energy, apparatus, energy, apparatus, presented, herein, energy, conversion, module, containing,...|
|[diesel, invention, provides, inlet, processing, diesel, diesel, inlet, treatment, diesel, charac...|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

**EMR hardware settings:**

- Master: m5.2xlarge
  8 vCore, 32 GiB memory, EBS only storage
  EBS Storage:128 GiB
- Core (10x) : m5.4xlarge
  16 vCore, 64 GiB memory, EBS only storage
  EBS Storage:256 GiB

**`spark-submit` settings:**

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf "spark.executor.instances=40" --conf "spark.default.parallelism=640" --conf "spark.executor.cores=4" --conf "spark.executor.memory=12g" --conf "spark.driver.memory=12g" --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=12g" --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false" run_program.py
```

**`Word2Vec` settings (if not mentioned, I use default):**

- `vectorSize=200`
- `minCount=5`
- `numIterations=15`
- `numPartitions=120`

**Some more notes:**

- The cluster utilizes approximately 70% cpu during estimation
- Total ram usage is about 50-60% during estimation

Should I increase the `numPartitions` to make use of approx 100% cpu utilization? How much (or to what extend) will it reduce the accuracy of the model? How should I set `numIterations`? What would be sufficient in this case?

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why so large corpus is a must?

Comment: @Nacho so you suggest sampling the corpus and estimate ```Word2Vec``` on that?

Comment: If there is not an special reason to have so large corpus, I suggest to obtain a sample of 15-20Gb max. This would be rather enough for general purpose applications.

Comment: Alright that seems reasonable. I will give it a try :)